# How to use a variable's value as a command name in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a variable's value as a command name in discord.py
here is my code:

```
print('Please paste your token:  ')
token = input()
print('Please input your prefix:  ')
prefix = input()
print('Command name:  ')
command_name = input()
print('What would you like to reply with:  ')
command_reply = input()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
@bot.event
async def  on_ready():
    print("Ready !")
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('**pong**')
@bot.command()
async def command_name(ctx):
  await ctx.send(command_reply)
bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Ok... What is the error/bug? What do you need help with? Please give us more details.

Comment: i need help setting the command name as the command name variable

Comment: @bot.command()
async def command_name(ctx):
  await ctx.send(command_reply)

command_name = 'test'
expected = 'USER INPUT'

Comment: nothing, i need to get the users input and set the input as a command name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use this with on_message event like this :

```py
print('Please paste your token:  ')
token = input()
print('Please input your prefix:  ')
prefix = input()
print('Command name:  ')
command_name = input()
print('What would you like to reply with:  ')
command_reply = input()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
@bot.event
async def  on_ready():
    print("Ready !")
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('**pong**')
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower.startwith(prefix+command_name):
        await ctx.send(command_reply)
bot.run(token)
```